# Does the read/write method in SocketChannel blocking the current thread while executing?

Tags: java, nio

In my view, the read/write method would not blocking when there are no data coming or writing.
Such as, 
in server:

```
ServerSocketChannel channel = key.channel();
SocketChannel c = channel.accept();
c.configureBlocking(false);
c.read(byteBuffer);
```

In client:

```
SocketChannel c = SocketChannel.open();
c.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8088));
c.close();
```

the `c.read(byteBuffer);`would not block, so we said this method is no-block.

BUT my question is, when there are a large number of data read in `c.read(byteBuffer);`, whether this method would take more time to execute? Or it would just step over and then execute next lines? If it would take more time, is it a no-block method? And if it step over, how can I know the ByteBuffer finish reading?

Comment: A non-blocking call will only return data that is immediately available.  The only additional execution time is the microseconds needed to transfer the data.  As for “finish reading,” that is something only you can define.

Comment: @VGR In this way, It will return immediately, and in this moment, the data maybe in reading, when the data is read completely?

Comment: It will return when all the data that is immediately available and will fit into your `ByteBuffer` has been transferred. This can be zero. It will not block in non-blocking mode, obviously. 'Read completely' doesn't mean anything, as @VGR already stated.